# Get the index of the common elements of two arrays, A and B, using the Numpy library in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to get the index of the common elements of array A and B in Python, similar to the `intersect` function in Matlab.
For example, in Matlab, for the arrays:

```
A = [[1 2]
     [3 4]
     [5 6]
     [7 8]];

B = [[1 5]
     [3 4]
     [6 6]
     [7 8]];
[C,ia,ib] = intersect(A, B, 'rows', 'stable');
output:
    ib = [2;4]
```

That is, elements 2 and 4 of B are common to A.
Now using the Numpy library in Python there is the `intersect1D` function, but only for 1D arrays. There are several ways to obtain the intersection of the arrays A and B by rows for example:

```
C = (A[:, None] == B).all(-1).any(1)
# Intersection
print(A[C]) 

output: [[3 4]
          7 8]]
```

But how can I get the index (ib) of the common values of A in B, so that `C = B[ib, :]` like the above function in Matlab.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `np.where((A[:, None] == B).all(-1).any(1) == True)` it is 0 indexed

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I understand, with the code I get the values that are common, but how can I get the indices of the elements of array B that are common, that is, the second and fourth elements.

Comment: To get for `B`, just swap `np.where((B[:, None] == A).all(-1).any(1) == True)`, it will give you `(array([1, 3]),)` , since index starts from 0 not 1, it is `1, 3` @Yro